# Unable to understand why one should not use /usr/src/linux for kernel development

Tags: linux, build, linux-kernel, kernel

I was reading "Linux Kernel Development" by Robert Love. I came across a line which I am unable to understand fully:-

**`The kernel source is installed in /usr/src/linux. You should not use this source tree for development because the kernel version against which your C library is compiled is often linked to this tree.`**

It looks like I am unable to relate it with some very basic concept.

Comment: I am unsure, but this note seems outdated: Currently `libc` is shipped with  its own copy of kernel-related include files, so it is not dependent from kernel's tree.

Comment: I believe it was so you could create patches against a vanilla tree. Yes, it's outdated. Use git.

Answer (score 0):

The /usr/src/linux area has a (usually incomplete) set of kernel headers that are used by the library header files. They should match the library, and not get messed up. Headers in /usr/include/linux are "private" but these should be those headers which were used in a compilation of your libraries (notably glibc) and hacking around the with a link in /usr/src is a mistake as Linus tried to explain many times - sometimes quite forcibly. Headers used in a kernel compilation are NOT searched for in subdirectories of /usr/src/linux but are specific to a kernel version and can be drastically different between different versions, or at least you do not have any guarantees that they are not.